# Plotly makes VS code freezed

Tags: visual-studio-code, plotly

I'm using plotly in vs code (*.ipynb).

But it is too slow when shows the plot.
After `fig.show()`, vs code stopped around 10 sec. Finally it shows the plot, but still it's hard to scroll vs code and also hard to use interactive options in the plot. When i clicked something in the plot, it stopped again.

My office computer have no graphic card, is that makes any problem?

Comment: How much data are you plotting?

Comment: sorry for late. 10000 rows. and i don't know why but suddenly it works with no freeze. :) thanks!